# Spring Cloud Stream + Avro

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream

I am unable to send an Avro message using a functional supplier. SCSt tries to send the message as a JSON and fails. Could someone point out if there are any additional configurations needed?

Here's the functional bean for the Supplier

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Sensor> supplier() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return () -> Sensor.newBuilder()
        .setId("id")
        .setTemperature(random.nextFloat())
        .setAcceleration(random.nextFloat())
        .setVelocity(random.nextFloat())
        .build();
}
```

and the configuration

```
spring:
  cloud:
    schema-registry-client:
      endpoint: http://localhost:8990
    schema:
      avro:
        schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
    stream:
      function:
        definition: supplier
        bindings:
          supplier-out-0: sensor
      bindings:
        sensor:
          destination: sensor-exchange
          group: sensor-queue
          content-type: application/*+avro
```

Comment: Here is an demo of using SCSt and avro together. This demo however uses Confluent's schema registry and native encoding, but should give you an idea: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro

Comment: Take a look at the configuration and the way `StreamBridge` API is used along with a `Supplier`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @sobychacko. The sample uses native encoding and specifies a Kafka Serializer but I want to use the built-in AvroSchemaRegistryMessageConverter to serialize/deseralize. Now, StreamBridge takes in a MimeType and when I specify application/+avro as the MimeType, messages gets converted correctly. I do not know how to set such MimeType for a Supplier functional bean other than the content-type header which I have already configured.

Comment: which schema registry are you using?

Comment: Spring's (@SchemaRegistryServer) on 3.0.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an issue where the conversion happens. I filed an issue in Spring Cloud Function: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/611

As a workaround, you can use the content type as: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings...content-type: application/+avro` without the wildcard type in the producer configuration. When that above-mentioned issue is fixed, then you can continue using the content type with a wildcard in it (`application/*+avro`). Sorry about the inconvenience.

I updated [this sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-vanilla-kafka-binder) to reflect this workaround which will be reverted when we get the proper fix.

Update: The issue in Spring Cloud Function is addressed in the `3.0.x` branch. Please use the following dependency to get the fix.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.12.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

With this, you can use the wildcard type in content type: `application/*+avro`.

`3.0.12.RELEASE` will be available next week.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this bug @sobychacko. I tested your workaround and it works. For now, I am using ```StreamBridge``` and will start using the Supplier once this issue is resolved.

Comment: Good to know that it worked with `StreamBridge`. The issue I mentioned is already fixed in Spring Cloud Function. Please see my updates in the answer.